# MySQL: match-against vs like con joins: resultados diferentes

Tags: mysql, join, match

Estoy haciendo un buscador y me encuentro con que si uso `inner join` consigo resultados
diferentes a cuando uso `left join` y no entiendo por qué sucede en este caso. A continuación dejo las tablas y sus relaciones,
las consultas y los resultados obtenidos.

Las 4 variantes deberían entregar los mismos resultados.
Los dos cambios entre consultas son los `joins`: `inner join` por `left join`, y
`match-against` por `like`. Con los `left join`'s consigo el resultado esperado, con los `inner join`'s no.

Variantes `left join`:

```
select distinct be.id, be.razon_social, be.nombre_comercial
    from clientes be
    left join clientes_direcciones cd on cd.idCliente = be.id
    left join clientes_telefonos ct on ct.idCliente = be.id
    left join clientes_emails ce on ce.idCliente = be.id
    where (be.razon_social like '%mataderos%') or
    (be.nombre_comercial like '%mataderos%') or
    (cd.calle like '%mataderos%') or
    (cd.localidad like '%mataderos%') or
    (cd.partido like '%mataderos%') or
    (ct.nro like '%mataderos%') or
    (ce.email like '%mataderos%') ;
+----+--------------+------------------+
| id | razon_social | nombre_comercial |
+----+--------------+------------------+
|  2 | Prueba SRL   | Tu Prueba       |
+----+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0,01 sec)

    select distinct be.id, be.razon_social, be.nombre_comercial
    from clientes be
    left join clientes_direcciones cd on cd.idCliente = be.id
    left join clientes_telefonos ct on ct.idCliente = be.id
    left join clientes_emails ce on ce.idCliente = be.id
    where match(be.razon_social, be.nombre_comercial) against('mataderos') or
    (cd.calle like '%mataderos%') or
    (cd.localidad like '%mataderos%') or
    (cd.partido like '%mataderos%') or
    (ct.nro like '%mataderos%') or
    (ce.email like '%mataderos%') ;
+----+--------------+------------------+
| id | razon_social | nombre_comercial |
+----+--------------+------------------+
|  2 | Prueba SRL   | Tu Prueba       |
+----+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Variantes `inner join`:

```
select distinct be.id, be.razon_social, be.nombre_comercial
    from clientes be
    inner join clientes_direcciones cd on cd.idCliente = be.id
    inner join clientes_telefonos ct on ct.idCliente = be.id
    inner join clientes_emails ce on ce.idCliente = be.id
    where (be.razon_social like '%mataderos%') or
    (be.nombre_comercial like '%mataderos%') or
    (cd.calle like '%mataderos%') or
    (cd.localidad like '%mataderos%') or
    (cd.partido like '%mataderos%') or
    (ct.nro like '%mataderos%') or
    (ce.email like '%mataderos%') ;
Empty set (0,00 sec)

    select distinct be.id, be.razon_social, be.nombre_comercial
    from clientes be
    inner join clientes_direcciones cd on cd.idCliente = be.id
    inner join clientes_telefonos ct on ct.idCliente = be.id
    inner join clientes_emails ce on ce.idCliente = be.id
    where match(be.razon_social, be.nombre_comercial) against('mataderos') or
    (cd.calle like '%mataderos%') or
    (cd.localidad like '%mataderos%') or
    (cd.partido like '%mataderos%') or
    (ct.nro like '%mataderos%') or
    (ce.email like '%mataderos%') ;
Empty set (0,00 sec)
```

[Link a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d43409)

Las tablas:

```
create table clientes (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    razon_social varchar(100) not null,
    nombre_comercial varchar(100) not null,
    cuit varchar(12),
    es_consumidor_final tinyint not null default 1,
    observaciones longtext,
    idReferente int comment "Cliente que le refirió",
    esta_habilitado tinyint default 1,
    fecha_alta datetime not null,
    primary key (id),
    unique key uk_unico_cliente (razon_social, nombre_comercial, cuit)
)engine="InnoDB";
alter table clientes add fulltext(razon_social, nombre_comercial, cuit);
insert into clientes (razon_social, nombre_comercial, cuit, es_consumidor_final, fecha_alta, idReferente) values ("Consumidor Final", "Consumidor Final", null, 1, now(), null), ("Prueba SRL", "Tu Prueba", "12345678901", 1, now(), null), ("Otra Prueba SA", "Prueba 2", "12345678902", 1, now(), null), ("Carnes Pepe", "El Cerdo Servicial", "12345678903", 0, now(), 2), ("Granja Lapeño S.R.L.", "Autoservicio Nelly", "12345678904", 0, now(), 2), ("Tutor Nillo", "Ferretería Tutor Nillo", "", 0, now(), 4);

create table clientes_direcciones (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    idCliente int not null,
    nombre varchar(40) not null,
    calle varchar(60) not null,
    nro varchar(6) not null,
    entre_calle_1 varchar(60),
    entre_calle_2 varchar(60),
    localidad varchar(60) not null,
    partido varchar(60),
    cp varchar(10),
    es_ppal tinyint not null default 1,
    observaciones longtext,
    primary key (id)
)engine="InnoDB";
alter table clientes_direcciones add constraint fk_clientes_direcciones_cliente foreign key (idCliente) references clientes(id) on delete cascade;
insert into clientes_direcciones values (null, 2, "Principal", "De Las Carnes", "1536", "Av. Cerduna", "De Los Pollos", "Mataderos", "CABA", "1267", 1, "alguna aclaración");

create table clientes_telefonos (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    idCliente int not null,
    nro varchar(30) not null,
    es_movil tinyint not null,
    primary key (id)
)engine="InnoDB";
alter table clientes_telefonos add constraint fk_clientes_telefonos_cliente foreign key (idCliente) references clientes(id) on delete cascade;
insert into clientes_telefonos values (null, 2, "1122222222", 1), (null, 2, "1122222223", 1), (null, 3, "1122222224", 0);

create table clientes_emails (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    idCliente int not null,
    email varchar(50) not null,
    primary key (id)
)engine="InnoDB";
alter table clientes_emails add constraint fk_clientes_emails_cliente foreign key (idCliente) references clientes(id) on delete cascade;
```

Comment: ¿Conocés la diferencia entre `INNER JOIN` y `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @padaleiana si, la conozco (o eso creo. no he tenido inconvenientes en mi corta experiencia). Por eso puntualicé: en este caso. No se supone que debería obtener los mismos resultados en este caso? Si se encuentra una coincidencia de búsqueda debe devolver los datos del cliente.

Comment: Mostrá datos de ejemplo (como texto), así se puede reproducir lo que mencionás.

Comment: @padaleiana dejé los `create table`, con los `insert` y las `fk`'s, si es a lo que te referís. Edité la pregunta para añadir el link a SQLFiddle y reformatear el código.

Comment: " se supone que debería obtener los mismos resultados en este caso" no.. porque pensass que si???

Comment: no vas a tener resultados iguales con un join que con un left join, tienen conceptos diferentes, mientras que uno trae solamente a los que coinciden sí o sí, el otro trae a los que coincide + los datos de la tabla que haz colocado en el lado 'izquierdo'. en la práctica vas a encontrar que muchas veces si te podrán traer datos idénticos y es porque la tabla LEFT solamente tiene datos en la parte coincidente.